# Angular 2 - redirect login page

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

First call the template login (`login.component`). After login loading `app.component`.

My question is that,is this possible? how do I do?

Pergunta Editada:

I already use Can Activate. Sorry, i am still learning English. i want the following...

the bootstrap first call app.componet.

```html
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `  
      <ul class="sidebar-menu">
          <li class="header">Painel</li>
          <li class="treeview">
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>Loja</span>
              <span class="pull-right-container">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
              </span>
            </a>
            <ul class="treeview-menu">
              <li><a routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a routerLink="/users"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> <span>User</span></a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="content-wrapper">
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>`,

})
```

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{}
```

I want call `login.component` before call the `app.component`. Only after call the user login call `app.component`.

The menu will be loaded if `login.component` is a route because the menu would be loaded into `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes; it's possible -- and it's nicely described in the [advanced Routing & Navigation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) document, specifically in the [Milestone #4: Route Guards](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards) section.

You need to define a `CanActivate` guard and then protect the route with the guard:

**auth-guard.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate }    from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate() {
    console.log('AuthGuard#canActivate called');
    return true;
  }
}
```

Then use the guard to protect the portion of your site which requires authentication:

**admin.routing.ts**

```
import { AuthGuard }      from '../auth-guard.service';

const adminRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        children: [
          { path: 'crises', component: ManageCrisesComponent },
          { path: 'heroes', component: ManageHeroesComponent },
          { path: '', component: AdminDashboardComponent }
        ],
      }
    ]
  }
];

export const adminRouting: ModuleWithProviders =
    RouterModule.forChild(adminRoutes);
```

Comment: You're welcome, @RenatoSouzadeOliveira -- happy to help. :-)

Answer (score 3):

use **CanActivate**  you can allow user to visit page only if it's has been activated in route or redirect them to login.

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CanActivateAuthGuard } from './auth.service'

import { MyComponent } from './app.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '/home', component: MyComponent , canActivate: [CanActivateAuthGuard]}]
```

/*============*/

```
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class CanActivateAuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
        return true;
    }
    //Redirect the user before denying them access to this route
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
}
```